# How to detect duplicate words in a list and count them in a specific way

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, python-3.6

I've been learning python 3 for about 1 week now and I just can't find a way to do this, so here is my question.

I have this list:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'apple', 'banana']
```

Now I want to detect the duplicated words, count them, put the result in front of the word and print in a single string like this example:

Apple 3, Banana 2, tomato, carrot

Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'apple', 'banana']

', '.join(x + ' ' + str(arr.count(x)) for x in set(arr))
```

Returns this:

```
'banana 2, carrot 1, apple 3, tomato 1'
```

If you want to exclude `1`s:

```
', '.join(x + (' ' + str(arr.count(x)) if arr.count(x) > 1 else '') for x in set(arr))
```

Which produces:

```
'banana 2, carrot, apple 3, tomato'
```

An explanation:

This is what you would call a "comprehension." All I'm doing is iterating through each distinct element in `arr` (i.e. iterating through the set of unique elements in `arr`) and counting the number of times each one occurs in `arr` using `arr.count(x)` for each `x` in `set(arr)`. Everything else is just a way of getting your final string result in one line.

You also might be interested in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which effectively returns a dictionary of element: count pairs and makes it easy to quickly find the number of times a given element *x* occurs in your list. :

```
>>> collections.Counter(arr)
Counter({'apple': 3, 'banana': 2, 'carrot': 1, 'tomato': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted and also thanks for the explanation and the suggestion it  helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

the_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'apple', 'banana']

dct = Counter(the_list)

for i in range(len(dct.keys())):
     print dct.keys()[i], str(dct.values()[i])+", ",
```

Comment: thanks, counter and collection is something that i am trying to understand too.

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
    list = ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'tomato', 'carrot', 'apple', 'banana']
    d = {x:list.count(x) for x in list}
    print d
```

Output is:
{'tomato': 1, 'carrot': 1, 'apple': 3, 'banana': 2}

Comment: If you also sort then the code will be modified to                                                        d = {x:list.count(x) for x in list}
    for key in sorted(d):
        print"%s: %s" % (key, d[key])